# Qt5.5 QString indexOf odd result

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qt5.5

I am using Qt Creator to develop a C++ application and the debugger to examine the code, I am trying to understand some very odd results reported by the debugger.

```
    if ( intDelimiter == -1
      && (intOpB = strProcessed.indexOf("[")) >= 0
      && (intClB = strProcessed.indexOf("]", ++intOpB) >= 0) ) {
        strRef = strProcessed.mid(intOpB, intClB - intOpB);

        if ( pobjNode != NULL ) {
            strProcessed.replace(strRef, pobjNode->strGetAttr(strRef));
        }
```

I have a breakpoint on the line:

```
    strRef = strProcessed.mid(intOpB, intClB - intOpB);
```

In the code snippet above strProcessed contains:

```
    "1079-[height]"
```

When the breakpoint is hit, intClB contains 1 and intOpB contains 6.

intOpB is correct because the returned value from indexOf is 5 then its incremented before the search for "]", but intClB is not correct, why is the debugger reporting it as 1?  This makes no sense to me.

I am using:

```
    Qt Creator 3.6.0
    Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64bit)
    Built On Dec 15 2015 01:01:12
    Revision: b52c2f91f5
```

As spotted by king_nak, the corrected code should read:

```
    if ( intDelimiter == -1
    && ((intOpB = strProcessed.indexOf("[")) >= 0
    && (intClB = strProcessed.indexOf("]", ++intOpB)) >= 0) ) {
        strRef = strProcessed.mid(intOpB, intClB - intOpB);

        if ( pobjNode != NULL ) {
            strProcessed.replace(strRef, pobjNode->strGetAttr(strRef));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are these values only in the debugger? What happens when you print the values?

Comment: Yes, these are the values reported by the debugger, I will try printing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misplaced a brace:

```
(intClB = strProcessed.indexOf("]", ++intOpB) >= 0)
```

This assigns the result of `strProcessed.indexOf("]", ++intOpB) >= 0` to `intClB`, interpreted as `int`. As this statement is `true`, `intClB = 1`.

You want:

```
(intClB = strProcessed.indexOf("]", ++intOpB) ) >= 0
                                              ^ Brace here
```